# MVC: Anchor tag query strings at AJAX not pick up by Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, query-string

I am new to MVC and I am from ASP Classic background. I have the following `table` with `edit button` rendered by `Datatable`:

[image: Table Edit Button]

When I click on the `edit button` I wish to pass the query string of their respective `AutoINC` to the `Controller` and load the `PasswordDet` page.

**Javascript AJAX partial code for the Edit Button**

```
"columns": [
                { "data": "LoginID", "orderable" : true },
                { "data": "Name", "orderable": true },
                { "data": "DateCreated", "orderable": true },
                {
                    "orderable":false,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a href="/Password/PasswordDet/' + full.AutoINC + '"><img src="../../Content/myPics/edit-2-24.png" ></a>';
                    }
                },
            ],
```

**Controller**

I have tried the following `with` and `without` naming the query string

**Without Naming the query String**

[image: Tried A]

```
public ActionResult PasswordDet(string AutoINC)
        {
            //**** AutoINC is always NULL****
            return View();
        }
```

**With Naming the query String**

[image: Tried B with QueryString Name]

```
public ActionResult PasswordDet()
        {
            string AutoINC = Request.QueryString["AutoINC"];
            //**** AutoINC is always NULL****
            return View();
        }
```

**Moreover I have a New Button which doesn't pass any query string, how do I handle NULL**

```
"buttons": [
                {
                    text: 'New',
                    className: "btn btn-default",
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PasswordDet", "Password")';
                    },
                }
            ],
```

Comment: have you tried with this `<a href="/Password/PasswordDet?AutoINC=' + full.AutoINC + '">`

Comment: @Nilesh I have tried but still it returns `NULL` on top?

Comment: your query string url is not correct it should be generate like `localhost:50118/Password/PasswordDel?AutoINC=552`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your default route is something like as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default",                                              // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}  // Parameter defaults
);
```

So make your `PasswordDet` action method as follows:

```
public ActionResult PasswordDet(int id)
{
    // do whatever you want to with id here
    return View();
}
```

Now `localhost:50118/Password/PasswordDet/550` will surely map to the above action method having the `id` value `550`.